# TestNG custom error message on configuration failure

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

There is a possibility to create custom handling of test actions like: `onTestStart`, `onTestSuccess`, `onTestFailure` etc. They can be handled with TestNG custom listener ([here is an article about this](https://iamalittletester.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/testng-custom-listeners-itestlistener/)).

But all configurations failures, skips are not handled by it, e.g. methods defined with annotations `@BeforeTest`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass` etc. And I've got log like this:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method org.testng.internal.ConfigurationMethod.setUp() didn't finish within the time-out 10000
...
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass openModule1
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass closeModule1
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass openModule2
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass closeModule2
SKIPPED: testOpenTabs
SKIPPED: testPrint
SKIPPED: testFilterDataRequest
```

Is there any possibility to create listener for configuration actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is done with `IConfigurationListener`. ConfigurationListener class would look something like this:

```
public class ConfigurationListener implements IConfigurationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult itr) {
        Logger.log("LOG From ConfigurationListener onConfigurationSuccess:: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult itr) {
        Logger.log("LOG From ConfigurationListener onConfigurationFailure:: ");     
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult itr) {
        Logger.log("LOG From ConfigurationListener onConfigurationSkip:: ");        
    }

}
```

And do not forget to provide Listeners to TestNG, e.g. by using annotation with your base test class:

```
@Listeners({ TestListener.class, ConfigurationListener.class})
public class TestBase {
    ...
```

Here is a [nice article about different listeners](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-listeners-example/) in [testng](/questions/tagged/testng)